# Calculate Geometric and Arithmetic Mean

Tags: java, statistics, data-mining

I am trying to make general class to calculate Geometric mean using exponential of the arithmetic mean of logarithms , and Arithmetic Mean.

I am looking for some general feedback on how I can improve the structure and efficiency of my code.

```
package analysis.statistic;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Mean {

/**
 * this function calculate geometric mean using the exponential of the
 * arithmetic mean of logarithms
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>(-1)^m * 1/n-rt(product(numbers)) = (-1)^m exp(1/n
 * sum(ln(numbers[i])))
 * <li>n : is length of numbers</li>
 * <li>m : is number of negative values</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param numbers
 * @return geometric mean
 *         <ul>
 *         <li>NAN : if numbers array is empty</li>
 *         <li>0 :if numbers array contain 0 value</li>
 *         <li>negative value : if numbers array contains odd negative
 *         values
 *         <li>positive value : if numbers array contains even negative
 *         values or just positive values
 *         </ul>
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if numbers array are null
 */
public static double geometricMean(int... numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }

    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    int nNegativeValues = 0;
    double logarithmSum = 0;

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (i > 0) {
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i);

        } else if (i < 0) {
            nNegativeValues += 1;
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i * -1);
        } else if (i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int length = numbers.length;

    return expOfArithMeanOfLogs(nNegativeValues, logarithmSum, length);

}

/**
 * Works just like {@link Mean#geometricMean(int...)} except the array
 * contains long numbers
 */
public static double geometricMean(long... numbers) {

    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }

    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    int nNegativeValues = 0;
    double logarithmSum = 0;

    for (long i : numbers) {
        if (i > 0) {
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i);

        } else if (i < 0) {
            nNegativeValues += 1;
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i * -1);
        } else if (i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return expOfArithMeanOfLogs(nNegativeValues, logarithmSum, numbers.length);

}

/**
 * Works just like {@link Mean#Mean#geometricMean(int...)} except the array
 * contains double numbers
 */
public static double geometricMean(double... numbers) {

    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }

    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    int nNegativeValues = 0;
    double logarithmSum = 0;

    for (double i : numbers) {
        if (i > 0) {
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i);

        } else if (i < 0) {
            nNegativeValues += 1;
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i * -1);
        } else if (i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return expOfArithMeanOfLogs(nNegativeValues, logarithmSum, numbers.length);

}

/**
 * Works just like {@link Mean#geometricMean(int...)} except the array
 * contains float numbers
 */
public static double geometricMean(float... numbers) {

    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    int nNegativeValues = 0;
    double logarithmSum = 0;

    for (float i : numbers) {
        if (i > 0) {
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i);

        } else if (i < 0) {
            nNegativeValues += 1;
            logarithmSum += Math.log(i * -1);
        } else if (i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return expOfArithMeanOfLogs(nNegativeValues, logarithmSum, numbers.length);

}

/**
 * Return Exponential of the arithmetic mean of logarithms
 * 
 * @param m
 *            is the number of negative numbers
 * @param logarithmSum
 *            is arithmetic mean of logarithms
 * @param n
 *            numbers of values
 * @return exponential of the arithmetic mean of logarithms
 */
private static double expOfArithMeanOfLogs(int m, double logarithmSum, int n) {

    double expOfLogarithms = Math.exp(((double) 1 / n) * logarithmSum);

    if (m != 0) {
        expOfLogarithms = expOfLogarithms * Math.pow(-1, m);
    }
    return expOfLogarithms;
}

/**
 * The mean is the average of the numbers.
 * <li>sum(numbers[i])/n</li>
 * <li>n : length of array numbers</li>
 * 
 * @param numbers
 *            integers
 * @return average of the numbers
 *         <ul>
 *         <li>NAN : if array numbers is empty
 *         <li>average : if contains numbers
 *         </ul>
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if numbers array is null
 */
public static double arithmeticMean(int... numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    return (double) Arrays.stream(numbers).parallel().sum() / numbers.length;

}

/**
 * Works just like {@link Mean#arithmeticMean(int...)} except the array
 * contains double numbers and
 * 
 * @param numbers
 *             double
 */
public static double arithmeticMean(double... numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    return (double) Arrays.stream(numbers).parallel().sum() / numbers.length;
}

/**
 * Works just like {@link Mean#arithmeticMean(int...)} except the array
 * contains long numbers and
 * 
 * @param numbers
 *             long
 */
public static double arithmeticMean(long... numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    return (double) Arrays.stream(numbers).parallel().sum() / numbers.length;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you test your code with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: I found a problem when using **arithmeticMean(int..)** with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` so i rewrite the function like blow
    `public static double arithmeticMean(int... numbers) {
  long tmp = 0;
  for (int i : numbers) {
   tmp += i;
  }
  return (double) tmp / numbers.length;

     }`

Comment: This will only prevent an overflow in `arithmeticMean(int...)`, and the *only* reason a `long` overflow cannot occur now is that the size of an array is limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and `Integer.MIN_VALUE * Integer.MAX_VALUE > Long.MIN_VALUE`. Anyway, an overflow could also have occurred here with `int` values other than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. I think what @RolandIllig was actually referring to is the fact that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the *only* value where your *geometric* mean method will fail, because it's the only `int` value whose additive inverse cannot be represented as an `int`.

Comment: @Stingy thanks for your comment, what do you recommend to solve the fail of geometric mean method with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: @EslamAli Well, range limits are a part of primitive values, and if you use primitive values, you have to live with the fact that overflows are not illegal from the compiler's point of view but, in a way, part of their "contract", at least in Java. However, since in your geometric mean method, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (or `Long.MIN_VALUE`, respectively) is really a special case, you could throw an `ArithmeticException`, thereby making it a part of your method's contract that an overflow can never occur.

Answer (score 4):

In general, your code looks fine. Here are some suggestions:

- In chained `if`-`else` clauses where the final `if`-clause is supposed to represent all cases that are not covered by the preceding `if`-clauses, like this one:

  ```java
  if (i > 0) {
      // ...
  } else if (i < 0) {
      // ...
  } else if (i == 0) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  It is less ambiguous to omit the final `if` clause and make the last condition a simple `else` without an `if`. That way, not only you, but also the compiler knows that this is supposed to be the "default" case, which means the structure of the code represents your intention more closely. To confirm your assumption that the default case is indeed only whenever `i == 0`, you can use an assertion instead:

  ```java
  if (i > 0) {
      // ...
  } else if (i < 0) {
      // ...
  } else {
      assert i == 0;
      // ...
  }
  ```

  If you write your code like this, then an `AssertionError` will, should the situation arise, alert you to the fact that, when `i` is either a `float` or a `double`, `!(i > 0) && !(i < 0)` is actually *not* equivalent to `i == 0`, because `i` might represent `Float.NaN` or `Double.NaN`, in which case neither of the three conditions in your original code will evaluate to `true`. This means that, if somebody slips a `NaN` into the arguments, your method will only sum the logarithms of all non-`NaN` input values, but will calculate the mean based on the total number of arguments, including the NaN-values, thus producing an erroneous result (not to mention the scenario where the input array consists entirely of `NaN`s).
- You can reduce code duplication by coding the algorithm calculating the geometric mean for `double...` and `long...` input values only and delegating the methods for `int...` and `float...` to those two methods. It seems that, since the advent of Java 8, conversions like `int[]` to `long[]` are actually [pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882512/convert-an-int-array-to-long-array-using-java-8).

  Actually, you could even delegate the `long...` method to the `double...` method. While a conversion from `long` to `double` might be lossy, the only thing you are doing with the input values is passing them to `Math.log(double)`, so they will be converted to a `double` anyway before any calculations are performed.
- Here:

  ```java
  if (m != 0) {
      expOfLogarithms = expOfLogarithms * Math.pow(-1, m);
  }
  ```

  The `if` clause is redundant, because any number except 0 raised to the power of 0 is 1, so the effect of the code with be the same without the `if` clause.
- About the documentation of `geometricMean(int...)`:

  - The general description says that it calculates the geometric mean "using the exponential of the arithmetic mean of logarithms". This is true only if the numbers don't contain zero. You might update the general description to specify that, regardless of what the description for `return` says.
  - The wording "if numbers array contains odd negative values" is confusing, because it's not about whether the values themselves are odd, but whether the number of negative values is odd (same goes for the description when a positive value is returned).
  - Zero is an even number, so you don't need to list this case explicitly in the description for when a positive value is returned.
- You forgot to check for `null` in `geometricMean(float...)`.
- You can omit the class name in a `{@link}` tag if you link to the same class, so `{@link #geometricMean(int...)}` will be valid as well (by the way, the link in the documentation of `geometricMean(double...)` is faulty).
- There is a shortcut for checking arguments against being `null`:

  ```java
  Objects.requireNonNull(numbers, "numbers must be not null");
  ```

  This will throw a `NullPointerException` instead of an `IllegalArgumentException`.
- In `arithmeticMean(double...)`, you don't need to cast the sum of the stream to `double`, because `DoubleStream.sum()` already returns a `double`.

Answer (score 4):

You are currently repeating the code unnecessarily. Instead of writing the same algorithm three times, you should define an inner helper class like this:

```
private static class Stats {
    private int n;
    private double logsum;
    private double sign = 1.0;

    void add(double num) {
        n++;
        if (num < 0) {
            logsum += Math.log(-num);
            sign = -sign;
        } else {
            logsum += Math.log(num);
        }
    }

    double getGeometricMean() {
        return sign * Math.exp(logsum / n);
    }
}
```

Instead of counting the number of negative numbers, you only need to remember whether it was an even or odd number of numbers. Therefore the `sign` field toggles between `1.0` and `-1.0`.

Then you can use this class in all three methods, avoiding duplicate code:

```
public static double geometricMean(int... numbers) {
    Stats stats = new Stats();
    for (int number : numbers) {
        if (number == 0) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        stats.add(number);
    }
    return stats.getGeometricMean();
}
```

---

The Javadoc of all the methods should be consistent. In `geometricMean(int...)` it starts with `this function calculate geometric`, which is wrong English.

- Conventionally, Javadoc starts with an uppercase letter.
- The `this function` is redundant and should be left out.
- The `calculate` has to be `calculates`, like in the other methods.
- The Javadoc for methods and classes ends with a full stop.
- There should be no space before the colon.
- Having an empty `@param numbers` without any further explanation is useless. It just states that *there is* a parameter of that name, which is clearly visible from the code. So either describe the parameter, or remove that empty `@param` declaration.
- The Javadoc should describe the effects of calling the method, not the implementation details. Your use of logarithms can be considered an implementation detail.

So the Javadoc should look like:

```
/**
 * Calculates the geometric mean of the given numbers.
 *
 * @return ...
 */
```

The Javadoc for `arithmeticMean(int...)` is missing the `<ul>` tags around the `<li>` tags.

The code for `arithmeticMean` currently looks like this:

```
public static double arithmeticMean(long... numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers must be not null");
    }
    if (numbers.length == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    return (double) Arrays.stream(numbers).parallel().sum() / numbers.length;
}
```

I would write the following instead:

```
public static double arithmeticMean(long... numbers) {
    return (double) Arrays.stream(numbers).sum() / numbers.length;
}
```

I left out the null check since even without the check a `NullPointerException` is thrown pretty early by the `Arrays.stream` method.

I left out the special case for `length == 0`, since `0.0 / 0` is defined to be `NaN`.

I removed the `.parallel()` call since summing up doubles can lead to different results depending on the exact order.

If you want reproducible results, use `StrictMath.log/exp` instead of `Math.log/exp`.

---

Depending on your needs for precision, you should look at the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), so that you don't lose any precision while adding up all the logarithms.

---

The Javadocs for `arithmeticMean` have unfinished sentences.